# Difference between dot notation and square brackets in Flask templates

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

What's the difference between using square brackets or dot notation in the Flask web framework?  Both seem to work, for example:

In the Python script I can set `session['username'] = 'Geraint'`.  I can then access it the template using `{{ session['username'] }}` or `{{ session.username }}`

What's the difference between the two?  The docs seem to favour the dot notation so should that be used in *all* cases?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a feature of Jinja2, see the [*Variables* section](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.1.x/templates/#variables) of the *Template Designer* documentation:

> You can use a dot (`.`) to access attributes of a variable in addition to the standard Python `__getitem__` “subscript” syntax (`[]`).

This is a *convenience* feature:

> For the sake of convenience, `foo.bar` in Jinja2 does the following things on the Python layer:
>
> - check for an attribute called *bar* on *foo* (`getattr(foo, 'bar')`)
> - if there is not, check for an item `'bar'` in *foo* (`foo.__getitem__('bar')`)
> - if there is not, return an undefined object.
>
> `foo['bar']` works mostly the same with a small difference in sequence:
>
> - check for an item `'bar'` in *foo*. (`foo.__getitem__('bar')`)
> - if there is not, check for an attribute called *bar* on *foo*. (`getattr(foo, 'bar')`)
> - if there is not, return an undefined object.
>
> This is important if an object has an item and attribute with the same name. Additionally, the `attr()` filter only looks up attributes.

So if you use the attribute access (`{{ session.username }}`) then Jinja2 will first look for the *attribute*, then for the *key*. Since the [Flask `session` object](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/api/#flask.session) is a dictionary, this means you could potentially end up with the wrong result; if you have stored data under the key `get` in the session, `session.get` returns a dictionary method, but `session['get']` would return the actual value associated with the `'get'` key.