# What's the best way for a formula to provide attribute defaults?

Tags: salt-stack

Chef has a very elaborate (maybe too much so) scheme for cookbooks to provide default values of attributes. I think Puppet does something similar with class parameters where defaults usually go into `params.pp`. With Salt, I've seen:

1. specifying default value in dictionary/pillar lookups.
2. the `grains.filter_by` merging of default attribute values with user-provided pillar data (e.g., [map.jinja](https://github.com/saltstack-formulas/apache-formula/blob/master/apache/map.jinja) in [apache-formula](https://github.com/saltstack-formulas/apache-formula))
3. in a call to `file.managed` state, specifying default attribute values as the `defaults` parameter and user-specified pillar data as `context`.

Option 1 seems to be the most common, but has the drawback that the template file becomes very hard to read. It also requires repeating the default value whenever the lookup is done, making it very easy to make a mistake.

Option 2 feels closest in spirit to Chef's approach, but seems to expect the defaults broken down into a dictionary of cases based on some filtering attribute (e.g., the OS type recorded in grains).

Option 3 is not bad, but puts attribute defaults into the state file, instead  of separating them into their own file as they are with option 2.

Saltstack's [best practices doc](http://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/topics/best_practices.html) endorses Option 2, except that it doesn't address how to merge defaults with user-specified values without having to use `grains.filter_by`. Is there any way around it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The behavior of defaults.get changed in 2015.8, possibly due to a bug. This answer describes a compatible method of getting the same results in (at least) 2015.8 and later.**

Suppose your formula tree looks like this:

```
something/
    files/
        template.jinja
    init.sls
    defaults.yaml

# defaults.yaml
conf_location: /etc/something.conf
conf_source: salt://something/files/template.jinja

# pillar/something.sls
something:
  conf_location: /etc/something/something.conf
```

The idea is that formula defaults are in defaults.yaml, but can be overridden in pillar. Anything not provided in pillar should use the value in defaults. You can accomplish this with a few lines at the top of any given .sls:

```
# something/init.sls
{%- set pget = salt['pillar.get'] %} # Convenience alias
{%- import_yaml slspath + "/defaults.yaml" as defaults %}
{%- set something = pget('something', defaults, merge=True) %}

something-conf-file:
  file.managed:
    - name: {{ something.conf_location }}
    - source: {{ something.conf_source }}
    - template: jinja
    - context:
        slspath: {{ slspath }}
    ... and so on.
```

What this does: The contents of defaults.yaml are loaded in as a nested dictionary. That nested dictionary is then merged with the contents of the `something` pillar key, with the pillar winning conflicts. The result is a nested dictionary containing both the defaults and any pillar overrides, which can then be used directly without concern to where a particular value came from.

`slspath` is not strictly required for this to work; it's a magic variable that contains the directory path to the currently-running sls. I like to use it because it decouples the formula from any particular location in the directory tree. It is not normally available from managed templates, which is why I pass it on as explicit context above. It may not work as expected in older versions, in which case you'll have to provide a path relative to the root of the salt tree.

The downside to this method is that, so far as I know, you can't access the final dictionary with salt's colon-based nested-keys syntax; you need to descend through it one level at a time. I have not had problems with that (dot syntax is easier to type anyway), but it is a downside. Another downside is the need for a few lines of boilerplate at the top of any .sls or template using the technique.

There are a few upsides. One is that you can loop over the final dictionary or its sub-dicts with `.items()` and the Right Thing will happen, which was not the case with defaults.get and which drove me insane. Another is that, if and when the salt team restores defaults.get's old functionality, the defaults/pillar structure suggested here is already compatible and they'll work fine side by side.

Comment: Sadly, this is the new correct answer. :-) I say "sadly", because it's less elegant than the old one, but that's the way it is.

Answer (score 4):

**Note: The behavior of defaults.get changed in version 2015.8, and so the method described here no longer works. I am leaving this answer for users of older versions and will post a similar method for current versions.**

`defaults.get` coupled with a `defaults.yaml` file should do what you want. Assume your formula tree looks like this:

```
my-formula/
    files/
        template.jinja
    init.sls
    defaults.yaml

# my-formula/init.sls
my-formula-conf-file:
  file.managed:
    - name: {{ salt['defaults.get']('conf_location') }}
    - source: {{ salt['defaults.get']('conf_source') }}
    ... and so on.

# defaults.yaml
conf_location: /etc/my-formula.conf
conf_source: salt://my-formula/files/template.jinja

# pillar/my-formula.sls
my-formula:
  conf_location: /etc/my-formula/something.conf
```

This will end with the configuration file placed at `/etc/my-formula/something.conf` (the pillar value) using `salt://my-formula/files/template.jinja` as the source (the default, for which no pillar override was supplied).

Note the unintuitive structure of the pillar and defaults files; `defaults.get` expects `defaults.yaml` to have its values at the root of the file, but expects the pillar overrides to be in a dictionary named after the formula, because consistency is for the weak.

The [documentation](http://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/modules/all/salt.modules.defaults.html) for defaults.get gives its example using `defaults.json` instead of `defaults.yaml`. That works but I find yaml much more readable. And writable.

There is a [bug](https://github.com/saltstack/salt/issues/19856) using defaults.get from inside a managed template rather than within the state file, and as far as I know it's still open. It can still be made to work; the workaround is behind the link.

Comment: Beautiful, thanks! (And an extra thank you for the pointer to the bug, that would really have tripped me up.)

Comment: No problem. I filed the linked bug report; I remember beating my head against the wall over it for quite some time.

Comment: It seems that after [this PR](https://github.com/saltstack/salt/pull/26903), `defaults.get` no longer retrieves an override from a pillar file, if one exists.

Comment: I've heard that in current versions it expects the same key path as pillar.get rather than the abbreviated one previously used. I'm not sure of the exact mechanics because my Salt is still a few versions behind.

Comment: Yes Fernando, I opened a bug for it: [saltstack/salt#29293](https://github.com/saltstack/salt/issues/29293). It's been labelled as a "high priority regression", so I hope it will get reverted soon. AFAIC, this alone prevents me from upgrading to recent releases of Saltstack. (And got me to start seriously looking at other config mgmt tools, since the cost of switching is still low for us at this point.)

Comment: Davor, I've posted a separate answer to handle the problem in more recent versions. If it suits you, you may want to mark that one as the answer, since this answer is broken in current versions.